# Need simple explanation on "Differentiation from first principles"

Tags: calculus

I'm following this eBook, but couldn't understand how the author explains the points as $A(x,y)$ and $B(x+δx,y+δy)$. Why B has more arguments which are $+δx$ and $+δy$ than A?

Also, the height of B which is $f(x+\delta x)$, why it use the $+δx$ other than the height of A which is only $f(x)$?

[image: part of the eBook]

Comment: in $B$, do not think of $\delta x$ as 'more arguments'. These are infinitesmal increases in the value of $x$, moving from $x \rightarrow x+ \delta x$ and similalry for $y$. This tiny change is the 'first principles' bedrock on which the Differential Calculus is built.

Comment: Try this out with some numbers and  draw that picture carefully. Suppose $f(x) = x^2$, $x=2$ and $\delta x = 0.01$. Then calculate all the other quantities. Follow that example as you follow the algebra in the book.

Comment: But, why A does not have "+δx", A is part of the function gradient. The previous example was solved by defining the difference of a triangle sides and finding the hypotenuse and that requires finding the result of dividing the difference of f(x2)-f(x1) over x2-x1, that's OK but I can't understand +δx part.

Comment: Why isn't A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2)? What is this "+δx" part? I found that it's quite a big subject in calculus. Should I read about it to understand my current problem?

Comment: Writing $A(x,y)$ is naming a point in this example. $A$ isn't a function, and neither is $B$. They're just the names of the two ordered pairs $(x,y)$ and $(x+\delta x, y+\delta y)$.

Comment: Think of $x$ as $x_1$ and $x+\delta x$ as $x_2$, then rewrite the figure in the notation of the previous example, which you understood. You'll find that it's just another way of saying the same thing, where $\delta x = x_2-x_1$.

Comment: OK, so x2 = x1 + δx. What about any point between A and B? How would they be determined? What are A and B anyway? Are they determined or they are just arbitrary chosen points for the example. And so if the function runs from minus to positive infinity, then I just have to stop the function and choose certain points to study the behavior of the function, is my conclusion logical? Thanks to this trainer I learned a lot from visualizing and explaining δx https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUvTyaaNkzM